# Was bringing the Skrulls to Earth a bad idea?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-marvels

In "the Marvels",

> Skrull refugees are sent to New Asgard.

However, Skrulls are banned on Earth, according to Secret Invasion. Did Captain Marvel not realize this?

Comment: In what way is it a bad idea if it's banned (beside breaking the law)?

Answer (score 4):

The MCU timeline has become a little confused due to various issues such as re-shoots, the writers and actors strikes.

In actuality, *The Marvels* was supposed to be released before *Secret Invasion* so technically, it hasn't happened yet.

Consequently, it's best to treat *The Marvels* as though the movie takes place before *Secret Invasion*.

> **The reason for all of these conspicuous disconnects is quite possibly because The Marvels was, for a long while there, supposed to come out before Secret Invasion.** A Captain Marvel sequel was announced in July 2019; Secret Invasion, in December 2020. Development on what would be titled The Marvels began mere weeks after Secret Invasion was announced, and the big-screen sequel began filming in July 2021. The Marvels has had five different release dates, the first three of which — 7/8/22, 11/11/22 and 2/17/23 — all pre-dated Secret Invasion‘s June 21, 2023 release.
>
> So it’s logical that The Marvels considered itself set before Secret Invasion… and yet, that still leaves continuity issues all over the place. If beautiful New Asgard was already home to a Skrull community, what exactly was Gravik’s beef? Also, where was Talos in all of this? This is where I speculate that The Marvels‘ character of Skrull Emperor Dro’ge, whose casting (Gary Lewis) was not announced until very recently, was originally meant to be Talos.
>
> Source: [TVLine](https://tvline.com/news/why-the-marvels-ignores-secret-invasion-series-explained-talos-death-super-skrull-giah-1235078449/)

Comment: According to the [official Disney+ MCU complete timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouZxz.jpg), The Marvels is set *after* Secret Invasion, not before.